# Production app: Invalid or unknown client (ID copied from credentials page)

Tags: ringcentral

I went through the sandbox testing and graduation procedure. My application got approved (for internal use), but I've been unable to use the new client ID.

The OAuth callback URL contains the error message:

```
GET /oauth2callback?error=invalid_request&error_description=OAU-230%3AInvalid%20or%20unknown%20client%3A%20xxxxxxxclientIdxxxxx
```

I copied my client ID several times from the application credentials page, it is correct and complete. The ID is repeated correctly inside the error message as well, so I know it's received on the production server. The production server URL is correct too.

What's going on here?

Comment: If you changed your Client Id, Client Secret and API server URL, it should work. If it's not working, please contact developer support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, all I had to do is wait. After graduating my application and getting the Approved message, RingCentral took a while longer for the new credentials to start working. I don't know how long it took, as I've waited 28 days to try again.